# The A-List of Foreign Actors

Tags: pattern, movies

To commemorate the 77th Golden Globe awards, held today by the Hollywood Foreign Press Association, here is a little puzzle involving foreign actors.

What do the following foreign actors have in common, and who is the missing actor at #2?

1. Chris Hemsworth
2. ?
3. Ralph Fiennes
4. Emma Thompson
5. John Cleese
6. Nicholas Hoult
7. Henry Cavill
8. Liam Neeson
9. Hugo Weaving
10. James McAvoy
11. Patrick Stewart
12. Antonio Banderas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Judith Olivia Dench, the British actor portraying **M** in many James Bond movies.

The actors share a common thing:

> They have all played roles with one letter names. I realized after finishing the list that the title is a clue here, The A-list:

Here's the list:

> 1. Chris Hemsworth - Agent **H** in Men in Black: International
> 2. <s>Tommy Lee Jones - Agent **K** in Men in Black</s> Judith Olivia Dench - **M** in many James Bond movies
> 3. Ralph Fiennes - **M**, in No Time to Die
> 4. Emma Thompson - Agent **O** in Men in Black: International
> 5. John Cleese - **Q** in Die Another Day
> 6. Nicholas Hoult - **R** in Warm Bodies
> 7. Henry Cavill - **S**uperman (His logo is just the **S**)
> 8. Liam Neeson - Agent High **T** in Men in Black: International
> 9. Hugo Weaving - **V** in V for Vendetta
> 10. James McAvoy - <s>Private James **W**. Miller in Band of Brothers</s> Professor **X** in X-men First Class
> 11. Patrich Stewart - Professor **X** in X-men Days of Future Past
> 12. Anotonio Banderas - **Z** in The Mask for Zorro

There are several options for the missing one:

> The list is in alphabetical order, so the options are any letter between H and M, **i, j, k, l**. Apparently there can be duplicates, so H and M are included.

My guess is that you're after

> <s>Agent **K** in Men in Black, since there are other Men in Black actors, but I could be wrong.</s>
> Judith Olivia Dench, the British actor portraying **M** in many James Bond movies.

Comment: #10 has played the same character as #11.

Comment: Yes, everything is now correct!

Comment: I will add that the reason I didn't put #2 in there to begin with is that I thought it would make the puzzle a little too obvious, as is why I didn't add Desmond Llewelyn or Ben Whishaw.  The others on the list are famous for roles other than the ones that put them on this list.

Comment: Why not Tommy Lee Jones though?  Is that a valid, alternate answer?

Comment: The puzzle specified that the actors were foreign. It turns out both OP and TLJ are American.